# Different drift and diffusion coefficients for the same Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

I have recently been taught the Fokker-Planck equation for diffusion, which says, for $t \geq s$:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x; t|y; s) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f(x, t)p(x; t|y; s)) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(g^2(x, t)p(x; t|y; s))$$

where $f(x, t)$ and $g(x, t)$ are the drift and the diffusion coefficients, respectively. We derived this equation by taking the limit of a discrete Markov process. However, I notice that I can keep the right hand side of the equation the same, but change the drift and the diffusion coefficients.

For example I can write:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x; t|y; s) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f'(x, t)p(x; t|y; s))$$
where $f'(x, t) = f(x, t) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (g^2(x, t)p(x; t|y; s))}{p(x; t|y; s)},$  so that it has a zero diffusion coefficient and a different drift. We can obviously also rearrange for it to have a non-zero diffusion coefficient.

It seems we can have multiple drift and diffusion pairs such that the evolution of the conditional probability density function is the same. But intuitively it seems that given the same conditional density function evolution, the diffusion process should also be the same.

I asked my teacher about it, and they said that we just consider the "simplest" form, but I don't find it satisfactory. I think I'm missing something very obvious here. Could someone please help me?

Comment: What you are missing is that $f'(x,t)$ depends on $p(x,t)\,.$ The transformed equation does not look linear unless you transform it back to its original form. Linear equations are a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: I don't think it should make a difference. Assume I know a solution for $p(x, t)$ of the original equation. I can then define $f'(x, t)$ using this known solution. The resulting PDE should still be satisfied by the original solution.

Comment: In both forms your equations have the same solutions. When you transform away the diffusion coefficient by absorbing it in to the drift has this changed the equation? I don't think so. It just looks different. Not even simpler.